# Identifying the parameters and finding an optimal solution to a problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I work in the Computer Graphics field, and I have a problem where I need to find the optimal solution for, but I'm not sure how to best formulate the problem mathematically, how to define the objective function, and finally - how best to find that optimal solution.

My problem is as follows:

I have a 3D scene, and in it several pre-defined points between which I can set my camera. Given some random target object in the scene, I'd like to find the point from which I have the best "view" on said object.
The parameters I need to take into account are:

1. Whether the target object is occluded by another object when viewed from the point.
2. The distance from that point to the target object's position is as small as possible. The object's position for that matter is its center and is known to us.
3. The angle between the viewing direction and the normal to the target object's surface is as small as possible. Ideally, the view point is positioned on the surface normal, which means that I'm exactly in front of the target object, and the angle is zero.

Effectively:

- $x_1 \in {0,1}$ and I'd like it to be 0 (not occluded).
- I want to minimize $x_2 \ge 0$.
- I want to minimize $0\le x_3 \le 90$

I'm not sure how to approach this. I realize that I need to set some utility functions for $x_2, x_3$ which will define how "important" each one is for me, and whether it's more important for me to be closer to the target object or more in front of it. I can tell that being in front of the object is more important than being close to it, because being close 1 meter to it but viewing it in an angle perpendicular to the surface normal will mean I won't see it at all, and it'll be better to view it from a 100 meters distance with some angle greater than zero. So, I guess it means I should "value" $x_3$ more than $x_2$. However, viewing the object from a kilometer away with a zero angle is much worse than viewing it from 10 meters away with an 80 degrees angle.

To sum up, I'm kind of lost on how to formulate the problem mathematically. I thought that Linear Programming is maybe what I'm looking for, but I have here two things I want to minimize.

Any directions and help will be much appreciated.

Tamir

Comment: Until you can formulate a utility function (objective function), this isn't a matter of mathematics or computer algorithms.  I doubt we can tell you what utility function to use because that depends on what your goals are and how you'll use the solution, which only you know.

Comment: How would one go about formulating such a function? Assuming you roughly understand what I want to achieve practically - identifying the point which gives best view on the object - what should I be aiming for with that function? A function of the form $ax_1 + bx_2$ where $a$ and $b$ are some arbitrarily set weights which I'll tweak until I'm satisfied with the results? Or something more like $x_1x_2$? Or something else entirely? I'm sorry, I just don't know - or rather, remember - a lot about utility functions.

Comment: I don't think I can answer that.  It depends on what you want to achieve and on the broader context.